# WPF Combox data updated but UI not updated - Updated code

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

Here is the code:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LowDLane, Mode=OneWay}"
                                  SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=CurrentLowDLaneIndex, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=0}"
                                  DropDownOpened="onLowDLaneDropDownOpened"
                                  SelectionChanged="onLowDLaneChanged">
</ComboBox>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow(ViewModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = model;
    }

    private void onLowDLaneDropDownOpened(object aSender, EventArgs aE)
    {
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).openedDropDown();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs** **Updated**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChangedHandler;

    public List<string> LowDLane
    {
        get { return mLowDLane; }
        set
        {
            mLowDLane = value;
           PropertyChangedHandler.raise(this, ()=> LowDLane);
        }
    }
    public void openedDropDown()
    {
        LowDLane = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};
    }

}
```

In other file PropertyChangedEventHandler is defined:

```
namespace System.ComponentModel
```

{

```
public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
```

}

Represents the method that will handle the System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
event raised when a property is changed on a component.

PropertyChangedEventHandler works well in other places so I don't think this is the problem here.

I created `ViewModel` object in other file, and passed it to `MainWindow`.
When I run the application, I can see the `LowDLane` property is updated, but the UI is not updated.

I have looked many similar questions, but none of them solved my issue.
Can someone help?

Comment: The code you posted won't compile. You claim to be invoking the `ViewModel.PropertyChanged` event delegate in the `LowDLane` property setter, but doing so requires two parameters. One might post an answer telling you to call `NotifyPropertyChanged()` there instead, but since the code you posted doesn't compile, it's obvious you didn't post real code in the first place, and so it's pointless to make any assumptions that the code in any way indicates what your actual code looks like. Fix your question so it includes an actual, good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add **UpdateSourceTrigger** property to Combo box itemSource binding and make Mode to TwoWay.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LowDLane, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Let me know if this solves the issue.

Comment: I somehow missed the implementation part of 'PropertyChanged' event and how it is being called and went ahead to check the binding to UI.

Comment: I have tried make Mode to TwoWay and set UpdateSourceTrigger, but still not slove my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `NotifyPropertychanged` method of yours inside your setter

```
public List<string> LowDLane
{
      get { return mLowDLane; }
      set
      {
         mLowDLane = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("LowDLane"); // here
      }
}
```

For more details see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx)

And you may want to use `CallerMemberName` Attribute in your code see [here](http://grenangen.se/node/75)